# Python Plotly doesn't show proper trace name

Tags: python, graphics, plotly, data-visualization, trading

So I'm trying to display a trace name on my graph

[image: My chart]

But for some reason, it's not displaying properly. As you can see there on the right-hand side it shows price_trace name instead of ma_trace name.

```
   def plot(self, margins: bool = True, ma: bool = False, ma2: bool = False):
    self.weekly_data = weekly_bars(self.m_data)
    self.data['plot'] = self.williams_r() * -1

    fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True,
                        vertical_spacing=0.02, row_heights=[100, 30])

    price_trace = go.Candlestick(x=self.weekly_data['Date'],
                                 open=self.weekly_data['Open'],
                                 close=self.weekly_data['Close'],
                                 high=self.weekly_data['High'],
                                 low=self.weekly_data['Low'],
                                 name=self.market)
    fig.add_trace(price_trace, row=1, col=1)

    # displaying MA
    if ma:
        ma_trace = go.Scatter(x=self.m_data['Date'],
                              y=self.m_data[f'{self.t_ma1}_ma_{self.ma1_period}'],
                              mode='lines',
                              name=f'{self.t_ma1}_ma_{self.ma1_period}')
        fig.add_trace(ma_trace, row=1, col=1)
    fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)

    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=self.data['Date'],
                             y=self.data['plot'], name=f'{self.category} Index'), row=2, col=1)

    # display 80/20 if wanted
    if margins:
        c_80 = [80 for _ in range(len(self.data['Date']))]
        c_20 = [20 for _ in range(len(self.data['Date']))]
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=self.data['Date'],
                                 y=pd.Series(c_20), name='20',
                                 line={'color': 'black', 'dash': 'dash'}), row=2, col=1)
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=self.data['Date'],
                                 y=pd.Series(c_80), name='80',
                                 line={'color': 'black', 'dash': 'dash'}), row=2, col=1)

    fig.update_layout(height=800, width=1300,
                      title_text=f"{self.market} {self.start}-{self.end} & {self.category} "
                                 f"Index")

    fig.update_traces(name=f'{self.market}', row=1, showlegend=True)
    fig.update_traces(row=2, showlegend=True)
    fig.update_xaxes(rangebreaks=[
        dict(bounds=["sat", "sun"]),  # hide weekends
    ])
    fig['layout']['hovermode'] = 'x unified'
    fig.show()
```

Comment: it's a bit hard to reproduce your plot because it's inside a class method without the class definition so it might be nice to include more of your code. but anyway, i am assuming that the trace isn't displaying properly even though you are passing the argument `ma = True`?

Comment: I've included the part responsible for plotting. Even if I add a full class definition you wouldn't be able to reproduce without properly formatted data which I'm calculating myself.

Yes, I'm passing ma = True